# Tables in database source panel of IntelliJ are not visible

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, oracle11g

I'm using IntelliJ 12.0.4 in combination with Oracle 11g XE edition. I've set up a schema and some tables and added that data source in IntelliJ. I have two types of tables:

- Tables without any kind of prefix (e. g. DB_USER)
- Tables with prefix TBL$ (e. g. TBL$EMPLOYEE)

From IntelliJ I can only see the tables without prefix, while the tables with prefix are invisible. I've also added synonyms for those tables with prefixes which I can see from IntelliJ. The problem is that I can't generate Hibernate mappings from those synonyms.

Does anyone know what went wrong? :)

Answer (score 1):

As a result of [addressing this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-34860) the loader filters out tables with 3 letter (or less) prefixes followed by `$`. These tables are considered Oracle internal (this type of prefix is often used for deleted tables).

There is no way to see such tables, consider renaming them.